# Anaconda graph-tool fails import can't find required libraries

Tags: python, boost, anaconda, miniconda

**The Problem:**

*After a fresh install of miniconda, graph-tool install fails on import. It would appear the libraries aren't being linked, or the python path is not set correctly.
If I install boost 1.55.0 and manually copy the library files to the graph-tool package folder it will get passed the boost dependency and fail elsewhere.*

```
cp -r /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/lib* /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/
```

*Not really sure why its failing with a fresh install and its asking for boost 1.55.0 when the package installs 1.6 boost.*

**Miniconda Install**

```
Miniconda2 will now be installed into this location:
/root/miniconda2

- Press ENTER to confirm the location
- Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
- Or specify a different location below

[/root/miniconda2] >>> /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda
PREFIX=/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda
installing: python-2.7.12-1 ...
installing: conda-env-2.5.2-py27_0 ...
installing: openssl-1.0.2h-1 ...
installing: pycosat-0.6.1-py27_1 ...
installing: pyyaml-3.11-py27_4 ...
installing: readline-6.2-2 ...
installing: requests-2.10.0-py27_0 ...
installing: ruamel_yaml-0.11.14-py27_0 ...
installing: sqlite-3.13.0-0 ...
installing: tk-8.5.18-0 ...
installing: yaml-0.1.6-0 ...
installing: zlib-1.2.8-3 ...
installing: conda-4.1.11-py27_0 ...
installing: pycrypto-2.6.1-py27_4 ...
installing: pip-8.1.2-py27_0 ...
installing: wheel-0.29.0-py27_0 ...
installing: setuptools-23.0.0-py27_0 ...
Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
creating default environment...
installation finished.
WARNING:
You currently have a PYTHONPATH environment variable set. This may cause
unexpected behavior when running the Python interpreter in Miniconda2.
For best results, please verify that your PYTHONPATH only points to
directories of packages that are compatible with the Python interpreter
in Miniconda2: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Miniconda2 install location
to PATH in your /root/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>> no

Thank you for installing Miniconda2!

Share your notebooks and packages on Anaconda Cloud!
Sign up for free: https://anaconda.org
```

**Env Vars**

```
PATH=/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PYTHONPATH=/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7:
```

**Install graoh-tool**

## conda install graph-tool

```
Fetching package metadata ...................................................................
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda:

The following packages will be downloaded:

package | build
---------------------------|-----------------
expat-2.1.0 | 0 365 KB defaults
gmp-5.1.2 | 2 594 KB r
icu-54.1 | 0 11.3 MB defaults
libgcc-4.8.5 | 1 922 KB r
libgfortran-1.0 | 0 170 KB defaults
m4-1.4.17 | 0 337 KB defaults
pixman-0.32.6 | 0 2.4 MB defaults
util-macros-1.19.0 | 1 21 KB ostrokach
libpng-1.6.22 | 0 214 KB defaults
libsigcpp-2.4.1 | 3 3.4 MB ostrokach
libxml2-2.9.2 | 0 4.2 MB defaults
mm-common-0.9.7 | 0 230 KB ostrokach
mpfr-3.1.2 | 0 407 KB r
pthread-stubs-0.3 | 0 2 KB ostrokach
sparsehash-2.0.2 | 0 80 KB ostrokach
boost-1.60.0 | py27_0 10.1 MB defaults
freetype-2.5.5 | 1 2.5 MB defaults
numpy-1.8.2 | py27_1 7.9 MB defaults
cgal-4.6 | 1 4.1 MB ostrokach
fontconfig-2.11.1 | 6 405 KB defaults
scipy-0.14.0 | np18py27_0 29.6 MB defaults
cairo-1.12.18 | 6 594 KB defaults
cairomm-1.10.0 | 2 123 KB ostrokach
py2cairo-1.10.0 | py27_2 36 KB defaults
graph-tool-2.2.35 | np18py27_1 44.5 MB ostrokach
------------------------------------------------------------
Total: 124.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

boost: 1.60.0-py27_0 defaults
cairo: 1.12.18-6 defaults
cairomm: 1.10.0-2 ostrokach
cgal: 4.6-1 ostrokach
expat: 2.1.0-0 defaults
fontconfig: 2.11.1-6 defaults
freetype: 2.5.5-1 defaults
gmp: 5.1.2-2 r
graph-tool: 2.2.35-np18py27_1 ostrokach
icu: 54.1-0 defaults
libgcc: 4.8.5-1 r
libgfortran: 1.0-0 defaults
libpng: 1.6.22-0 defaults
libsigcpp: 2.4.1-3 ostrokach
libxml2: 2.9.2-0 defaults
m4: 1.4.17-0 defaults
mm-common: 0.9.7-0 ostrokach
mpfr: 3.1.2-0 r
numpy: 1.8.2-py27_1 defaults
pixman: 0.32.6-0 defaults
pthread-stubs: 0.3-0 ostrokach
py2cairo: 1.10.0-py27_2 defaults
scipy: 0.14.0-np18py27_0 defaults
sparsehash: 2.0.2-0 ostrokach
util-macros: 1.19.0-1 ostrokach

Fetching packages ...
expat-2.1.0-0. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 606.14 kB/s
gmp-5.1.2-2.ta 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 655.34 kB/s
icu-54.1-0.tar 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:14 812.14 kB/s
libgcc-4.8.5-1 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01 720.76 kB/s
libgfortran-1. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 560.30 kB/s
m4-1.4.17-0.ta 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 630.55 kB/s
pixman-0.32.6- 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03 784.41 kB/s
util-macros-1. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 279.57 kB/s
libpng-1.6.22- 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 565.91 kB/s
libsigcpp-2.4. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04 793.74 kB/s
libxml2-2.9.2- 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:05 799.84 kB/s
mm-common-0.9. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 504.88 kB/s
mpfr-3.1.2-0.t 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 601.81 kB/s
pthread-stubs- 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 1.84 MB/s
sparsehash-2.0 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 353.08 kB/s
boost-1.60.0-p 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:13 808.89 kB/s
freetype-2.5.5 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03 779.81 kB/s
numpy-1.8.2-py 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:10 805.93 kB/s
cgal-4.6-1.tar 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:05 799.17 kB/s
fontconfig-2.1 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 671.60 kB/s
scipy-0.14.0-n 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:38 817.81 kB/s
cairo-1.12.18- 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 703.43 kB/s
cairomm-1.10.0 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 409.75 kB/s
py2cairo-1.10. 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 245.24 kB/s
graph-tool-2.2 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:01:04 728.37 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[ COMPLETE ]|###########################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[ COMPLETE ]|###########################################################################################################################| 100%
```

**Test Script**
    import pkgutil

```
pkg_list = list(pkgutil.iter_modules())

pkg_list = list(x[1] for x in pkg_list if x[2]==True)


def loadPackage(packages):
    for x in packages:
        print x
        try:
            y = __import__(x)
            print y
            y = None
        except Exception,e:
            print(x+" Error: "+str(e))

loadPackage(pkg_list)
```

**Testing Modules**

## python test.py

```
bsddb
bsddb Error: No module named _bsddb
compiler
<module 'compiler' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/compiler/__init__.pyc'>
ctypes
<module 'ctypes' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc'>
curses
<module 'curses' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.pyc'>
distutils
<module 'distutils' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.pyc'>
email
<module 'email' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.pyc'>
encodings
<module 'encodings' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc'>
hotshot
<module 'hotshot' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/hotshot/__init__.pyc'>
idlelib
<module 'idlelib' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/idlelib/__init__.pyc'>
importlib
<module 'importlib' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.pyc'>
json
<module 'json' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc'>
lib2to3
<module 'lib2to3' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/__init__.pyc'>
logging
<module 'logging' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
multiprocessing
<module 'multiprocessing' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.pyc'>
pydoc_data
<module 'pydoc_data' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/pydoc_data/__init__.pyc'>
sqlite3
<module 'sqlite3' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.pyc'>
unittest
<module 'unittest' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.pyc'>
wsgiref
<module 'wsgiref' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/__init__.pyc'>
xml
<module 'xml' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc'>
Crypto
<module 'Crypto' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/__init__.pyc'>
cairo
<module 'cairo' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.pyc'>
conda
<module 'conda' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/__init__.pyc'>
conda_env
<module 'conda_env' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_env/__init__.pyc'>
graph_tool
graph_tool Error: libboost_iostreams.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
numpy
<module 'numpy' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
pip
<module 'pip' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'>
requests
<module 'requests' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'>
ruamel_yaml
<module 'ruamel_yaml' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/__init__.pyc'>
scipy
<module 'scipy' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc'>
wheel
<module 'wheel' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/__init__.pyc'>
yaml
<module 'yaml' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.pyc'>
pkg_resources
<module 'pkg_resources' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py'>
setuptools
<module 'setuptools' from '/opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.py'>
```

**The Error:**
    graph_tool
    graph_tool Error: libboost_iostreams.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Conda info -a

**Current conda install:**

```
platform : linux-64
conda version : 4.1.11
conda-env version : 2.5.2
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 2.7.12.final.0
requests version : 2.10.0
root environment : /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda (writable)
default environment : /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda
envs directories : /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/envs
package cache : /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/pkgs
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/rdonnellyr/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/rdonnellyr/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/r/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/vgauthier/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/omnia/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/omnia/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/pkgw/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/pkgw/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/mw/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/mw/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/jacksongs/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/jacksongs/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/hargup/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/hargup/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bembom/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bembom/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/gus/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/gus/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/prometeia/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/prometeia/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/chenghlee/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/chenghlee/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bembom/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/bembom/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/getpantheon/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/getpantheon/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/asmeurer/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/asmeurer/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scitools/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/asmeurer/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/asmeurer/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/jacksongs/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/jacksongs/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/pdrops/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/pdrops/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/yuxiang/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/yuxiang/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/cqwz/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/cqwz/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/abergeron/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/abergeron/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ryan/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ryan/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scw/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/scw/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/rustychris/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/rustychris/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/meznom/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/meznom/noarch/
https://conda.anaconda.org/sssdgc/linux-64/
https://conda.anaconda.org/sssdgc/noarch/
config file : /root/.condarc
offline mode : False
is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
root * /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda

sys.version: 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (defa...
sys.prefix: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda
sys.executable: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/bin/python
conda location: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda
conda-build: None
conda-env: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/bin/conda-env
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: <not set>
PATH: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: /opt/app/workload/anaconda2/miniconda/lib/python2.7:
```

Comment: Can you try to pin `boost=1.55.0`. In general you got this package from a third party repository with erroneous dependency specifications. There won't be much we can do about it.

Comment: well I'm not sure how to pin the version of boost when im installing graph-tool, and on top of that this is a completely clean install, It is installing boost 1.6 shouldn't it install the version it needs?

Comment: you can install pkg-1.0.1 version by doing `conda install pkg=1.0.1`. You have to find a channel that provides 1.55.0 first, though. "shouldn't it install the version it needs" - Yes, but as I said, you are getting this package from a third party channel and the dependencies do not seem right.

Comment: should I set it not to upgrade dependencies then, because it will just upgrade to 1.6 because the graph-tool dependency is set to that.

Comment: I am running into **unbelievable** problems installing this library locally.  Perhaps the developers need to loosen their issue reporting requirements, because they have an uninstallable body of software